# SSL Wildcard Certification that covers more than one layer of subdomains?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I'm working on a site that provides bespoke websites to franchisees of a large organization.  Each franchisee is managed as a separate sub-domain and everything is handled by one set of servers, which parse off the sub-domain name, and then based on that, serve up the properly composed pages so that the overall site has standard branding, but portions of the page are customized for each franchisee.   So if the root domain is "delivery.com" for example, then a certain franchisee might have "newyork.delivery.com" as their unique domain, and another might be "chicago.delivery.com".  All of the sites are served by a single server (maybe load-balanced multiple servers) that uses the "newyork" or "chicago" subdomain to serve similar but different sites depending on which url you ask for.  To avoid having to come up with separate DNS entries for everything, we are using a wildcard DNS entry for "*.delivery.com" pointing to the single server (or loadbalancer).  Slick!

In order to provide SSL for this system, we went and asked for a wildcard SSL Certificate for "*.delivery.com" and that seems to have been wonderful except for one thing... if somebody accidentally types in "www.newyork.delivery.com" they get told that there's no SSL certificate and rather alarmingly that someone may be spoofing them for nefarious purposes!  Certainly not the type of messaging that's desired.  So the DNS lookup for "www.newyork.delivery.com" correctly resolves to our server, but before my code even gets executed on the server, the browser determines that the wildcard SSL certificate we have doesn't cover a 2nd level subdomain, and displays an error to the user.  So, as it turns out, for DNS entries "*.delivery.com" means "anything under the delivery.com domain, including multiple layers of subdomains".  But when asking for an SSL certificate, "*.delivery.com" means "one-level of subdomain only".  How do I ask for an SSL certificate that provides protection for an entire domain, including all of the subdomains (multiple levels deep) beneath that domain?  Barring that, it seems like my only solution would be to create CNAME entries for each of the fully-qualified subdomains I want to support, and then at least the error to the browser would be the less alarming "site not found" error.  Any other solutions would be appreciated!

Comment: This question was asked multiple times already here. Please see [Wildcard SSL certificate for second-level subdomain](https://serverfault.com/questions/104160/wildcard-ssl-certificate-for-second-level-subdomain), [Do I have to buy a second wildcard certificate for a subdomain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/627219/), [Can a wildcard SSL certificate secure host names of various depths?](https://serverfault.com/questions/933374/) and several others

Comment: You know which franchises exist and can create explicit dns records for them pointing to a server which has a web server supporting plain http (to redirect to https) and https. If necessary automate getting valid certificate(s) for all sites. You point the dns wildcard to a different IP and only run a webserver there on the plain http port. (Most people who type a random website address don’t specifically use https) From there you can redirect to either the correct https franchise page or your main https site “no franchises yet in Rochester NY / become a franchisee / nearest is Buffalo NY”

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, I had looked at all of those answers, trust me, and they don't mention SNI, or whether there was a configuration method of managing the issue, because, and I realize it was a subtle point, I don't actually NEED the SSL certificates to handle multiple levels, because my code actually removes the errant "www." from the URL and immediately redirects to the proper URL (i.e. user types "www.newyork.delivery.com" and I redirect to "newyork.delivery.com", which is entirely within the purview of the SSL certificate. But my code doesn't even get called because of the cert validation.

Comment: @SteveSauder: A HTTP redirect gets send by the server only AFTER the HTTPS connection was established. Thus if you want to redirect from `https://www.sub.example.com` to `https://sub.example.com` you need a valid certificate both for `www.sub.example.com` (origin) and for `sub.example.com` (target).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Multi-level wildcard certificates are not allowed by the standards

This *was* described more directly in the **obsolete** [RFC 2818, 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818.html#section-3.1):

> Names may contain the wildcard character `*` which is considered to match any single domain name component or component fragment. E.g., `*.a.com` matches `foo.a.com` but not `bar.foo.a.com`. `f*.com` matches `foo.com` but not `bar.com`.

In the current Internet Standard this still exists, but it is inherited from another (*proposed*) standard.

The HTTP Semantics [RFC 9110](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110) defines the rules for https Certificate Verification in [section 4.3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#section-4.3.4):

> In general, a client MUST verify the service identity using the verification process defined in [Section 6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#section-6) of [[RFC6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125.html)]. The client MUST construct a reference identity from the service's host: if the host is a literal IP address ([Section 4.3.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#https.ip-id)), the reference identity is an IP-ID, otherwise the host is a name and the reference identity is a DNS-ID.

The same limitation now comes from the [RFC 6125, 6.4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125.html#section-6.4.3) (Checking of Wildcard Certificates):

> If a client matches the reference identifier against a presented
> identifier whose DNS domain name portion contains the wildcard
> character `*`, the following rules apply:
>
> 1. The client SHOULD NOT attempt to match a presented identifier in
>    which the wildcard character comprises a label other than the
>    left-most label (e.g., do not match `bar.*.example.net`).
> 2. If the wildcard character is the only character of the left-most
>    label in the presented identifier, the client SHOULD NOT compare
>    against anything but the left-most label of the reference
>    identifier (e.g., `*.example.com` would match `foo.example.com` but
>    not `bar.foo.example.com` or `example.com`).

The second rule prevents you from using multi-level wildcard certificates, and the first rule tells that you could not have `www.*.example.com` certificates, either. (For completeness, there is a third rule, too, but I did not cite it because it does not relate to this question.)

### Wildcards in DNS matches multiple levels

As you have noticed, wildcards in DNS, as defined in [RFC 1034, 4.3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034#section-4.3.3), matches multiple levels.

> -- Another way to look at this is that the `*` label always matches at least one whole label and sometimes more, but always whole labels.
>
> Wildcard RRs do not apply:
>
> - When the query is in another zone.  That is, delegation cancels
>   the wildcard defaults.
> - When the query name or a name between the wildcard domain and
>   the query name is know to exist.  For example, if a wildcard
>   RR has an owner name of `*.X`, and the zone also contains RRs
>   attached to `B.X`, the wildcards would apply to queries for name
>   `Z.X` (presuming there is no explicit information for `Z.X`), but
>   not to `B.X`, `A.B.X`, or `X`.

(As this specification was not that clear and, thus, were implemented in multiple ways, [RFC 4592](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4592.html) updates it with clarifications and examples that are not meaningful to cite in this context.)

There is not really a way around this other than not using wildcards at all. This indeed means that you would have to either

1. accept the fact that those TLS errors for hostnames with additional labels will be shown when using wildcards in DNS or
2. stop using the wildcards and register every subdomain individually in the DNS.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation!  It seems strange to me that the two standards would be at odds in this way, but such is life.  I think your second solution is likely going to be the best way to manage this, because we do on AWS have fairly easy control of our DNS entries, so we can add and remove them as needed (and there is an API provided by AWS that we can use to do this programmatically).