# If a sub domain is secure with a SSL certificate, will the sub-subdomain also be secure?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a standard SSL certificate I just purchased from Godaddy. Now it won't let me use a wild card for issuing the certificate for my domain. It says that the * wild card is not included in my product. Which means that I can only secure one domain like `subdomain.example.com`.

Now my question is that if I get the certificate issued for `subdomain.example.com`, will it be valid for `subdomain2.subdomain.example.com` also?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A certificate will only be valid for the names it was issued for. But, a certificate can contain multiple names so in your case you could get  a certificate which contains both `subdomain.example.com` and `subdomain2.subdomain.com` or maybe just have `*.subdmain.example.com`. The latter would then match your subdomain2. Please not that a wildcard only matches a single label and that only a leftmost wildcard is possible, that is `*.*.example.com` is not possible and `*.example.com` will match `subdomain.example.com` but not  `subdomain2.subdomain.example.com` or `example.com`.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Only subdomain.example.com and possibly www.subdomain.example.com will be covered by a "standard" certificate - you would need to purchase a wildcard domain at a higher price to cover all subdomains.

You should be able to verify this by looking at the cert with a command like

```
openssl x509 -in certfile.crt -text -noout | grep "DNS"
```

Answer (score 0):

Wildcard SSL certificate can secure your all sub domains.

If your requirement is securing first level sub domains (sub1.domain.com, sub2.domain.com and sub*.domain.com), then certificate issue on any.domain.com

You need to secure second level sub domains(aaa.sub1.domain.com, bbb.sub1.domain.com and any.sub1.domain.com), in that case issue certificate on *.sub1.domain.com

For further information read this discussion - [Wildcard SSL certificate for second-level subdomain](https://serverfault.com/questions/104160/wildcard-ssl-certificate-for-second-level-subdomain/)