# LetsEncrypt certificate for nested wildcard subdomain

Tags: subdomain, lets-encrypt, wildcard

I've generated Lets Encrypt [wildcard certificate](https://medium.com/@saurabh6790/generate-wildcard-ssl-certificate-using-lets-encrypt-certbot-273e432794d7) for my domain `*.domain.com`.

I thought this certificate is valid for any nested subdomain `*.*.domain.com`, like `it.*.domain.com` or `fr.*.domain.com`. But browsers giving me error, that wildcard certificate was issued for `domain.com`, and not for `*.domain.com`. I've tried to issue new certificate for `*.*.domain.com` with CertBot and it's giving me error (multiple wildcards not allowed).

Is it possible to achieve this, or do I have to manually issue wildcard certificates for each 1st level subdomain?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The CertBot error you're seeing is accurate - SSL certificates are only valid for one domain layer - for example `*.domain.com` or `*.fr.domain.com` or `*.example.domain.com`. More information - specifically the RFC quote - is in [this SF answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/104160/wildcard-ssl-certificate-for-second-level-subdomain).

If you need subdomains of subdomains, you will need to create wildcards for each individual subdomain.

Comment: Thats unfortunate, so I need to generate 20 wildcard certificates :(

Comment: I'd personally question the logic of your DNS structure - most implementations tend to use hyphens or URL-rewriting to separate locales for precisely this reason. For example: `domain.com/uk` or `uk.domain.com` or `store-uk.domain.com`.

Comment: It depends on the site type. I found out that for content sites it makes sense to create numerous region-oriented subdomains like lang.theme_category.domain.com for better search engine indexing purposes.

Comment: Because each combination is considered as different resource which affects indexing frequency. In contrast,`domain.com/theme_category/lang/` is considered as one resource so you get less bot scans by the factor of langs * categories

Comment: Each combination is not a separate site - [source1](https://www.pi-datametrics.com/identify-seo-sub-domain-conflict-cannibalisation/) / [source2](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/subdomains-vs-subfolders-seo/239795/). Using subdomains like this will harm SEO, not help it. A better strategy would be `theme.domain.com/lang`, or even better would be to use the correct localised domain - for example `domain.fr` or `domain.de` or `domain.it` if you have the commercial clout to do so.

Comment: @CraigWatson My domain logic is I want to auto-generate domains like we.live.to.sk8.earth or sk8.or.die.on.sk8.earth. Wish there was a wildcard that allowed any level. The alternative is sk8-or-die-on.sk8.earth which is inconsistent and ugly.

Comment: @trusktr If you're auto-generating domains, you can auto-generate certificates. Easy. Multi-level wildcards is fundamentally not possible due to the trust relationships which exist in all modern browsers and also how the wildcard character is parsed.